# Swiftでの配列への大量のデータのappendとメモリの使用率等について

Tags: swift

Swiftでの配列とメモリの扱いについて知りたいです。

配列に大量の要素をappendする場合、変数に対して大量のデータを入れると、そのデータはメモリ内部に蓄積されたままになると思います。あまり望ましくない状態なのではないかと思います。

このデータをテキストファイルなどに保存しておくのが良いのか、userDefaultなどに保存するのが良いのか、どのような扱いをするのが良いのかアドバイスがほしいです。

以下のようなコードを試しました。
1秒間に100回ループを回して、配列に現在時刻を追加するだけのコードです。
配列に保存したデータは、一定数溜まったら、あとでprint文で使用します。
毎秒100回ループでprintを行います。
数十分から数時間のデータ記録と再生を想定しています。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer: Timer!
    var recordedArray:[String] = []
    var recordedArrayPlayCount = 0
    var play_or_rec = "rec"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        //0.01秒ごとに繰り返す、repeat every 3 seconds
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    
    @objc func update(tm: Timer) {
        //この関数を繰り返す、repeat this function
        if self.play_or_rec == "rec"
        {
            //recモードのときは配列に追加する
            let nowTime = getNowClockString()
            recordedArray.append(nowTime)
        }
        else if self.play_or_rec == "play"
        {
            //playモードのときはprintする
            if recordedArray.count > self.recordedArrayPlayCount
            {
                print(recordedArray[self.recordedArrayPlayCount])
                self.recordedArrayPlayCount += 1
            }
            else
            {
                self.play_or_rec = "rec"
            }
        }
    }
    
    //現在時刻の文字列を取得
    func getNowClockString() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
        let now = Date()
        return formatter.string(from: now)
    }
    
    //recordとplayとstopを切り替える
    @IBAction func playOrRecordButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if self.play_or_rec == "rec"//record状態からstop1へ移行
        {
            self.play_or_rec = "stop1"
        }
        else if self.play_or_rec == "stop1"//stop1状態からplay状態へ移行
        {
            self.play_or_rec = "play"
            self.recordedArrayPlayCount = 0
        }
        else if  self.play_or_rec == "play"//play状態からstop2状態へ移行
        {
            self.play_or_rec = "stop2"
        }
        else if  self.play_or_rec == "stop2"//stop2状態からrecord状態へ移行
        {
            self.play_or_rec = "rec"
        }
    }
    
}
```

playOrRecordButtonTappedの部分を、以下のようなコードに書き換えた場合、効果はあるのでしょうか？
stop状態の間は、userDefaultsにデータを預けて、配列を初期化しています。
こうすることで、メモリを空けて、ストレージ側にデータが行くのでマシンには優しい設計になるかと思ったのですが、どうでしょうか...?
正しくない設計でしょうか...?

```
    //recordとplayとstopを切り替える
    @IBAction func playOrRecordButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if self.play_or_rec == "rec" //record状態からstop1状態へ以降
        {
            //配列をuserDefaultsに保存
            userDefaults.set(self.recordedArray, forKey: "recordedArray")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
            
            //停止中はメモリを空けておきたいので、配列を初期化
            self.recordedArray = []
            
            self.play_or_rec = "stop1"
        }
        else if self.play_or_rec == "stop1"//stop1状態からplay状態へ以降
        {
            self.recordedArray = userDefaults.object(forKey: "recordedArray") as! [String]
            self.recordedArrayPlayCount = 0
            self.play_or_rec = "play"
        }
        else if  self.play_or_rec == "play"//play状態からstop2状態へ以降
        {
            //停止中はメモリを空けておきたいので、配列を初期化
            self.recordedArray = []
            
            self.play_or_rec = "stop2"
        }
        else if self.play_or_rec == "stop2"
        {
            self.play_or_rec = "rec"
        }
    }
```

メモリ等のパフォーマンスがよくなるように、よりよい方法があったら教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このケースの場合、フラグだけでは無く、配列の最大長を設定しておき、その条件判定も含めて保存するか決めた方が良さそうです。一定以上の配列長になった場合は常に保存し、メモリを無制限に使わないようにする必要があります。

また、UserDefaultsは大量のデータを入れるためのものではなく、基本的にアプリ設定などを保存するためのものです。特性として、大量データを入出力すると保存・読み出し共に大幅に性能が落ちてしまいます。
今回の場合は、テキストファイルでデータを保存するのが一番簡単でやりやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！その方法が良さそうですね。ただ、その方法を使用する場合でもやはりplayモードに移るときは1度すべてのテキストデータを配列に保存しないといけない気がします。テキストデータ内に区切り文字などを入れることで分割して必要な分だけ取り出し、すぐに読み込みに使った配列の初期化のようなことをするのがメモリ効率として良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 用途にもよるのですが、今回のケースだと１つの巨大ファイルにするよりは、配列の最大長になるか、モードが変わった時などにそれぞれ別名でファイルに保存するのが良い気がしています。そしてその時必要な分（必要なファイル）だけ読み込むのであれば、メモリの使用量がかなり抑えられます。後は、難しい方法ですが、例えばファイルを圧縮形式にしてしまって、部分解凍しながら読みだしたりという方法もあります。この場合は必要部分だけを解凍しているため、読み込む必要がある量自体が減ります。基本的にコンパイラがやるような部分のメモリの効率化は考えない方が良く、もっと大枠の部分で仕組み的に効率を良くするのが一番効果があると思います。

Comment: ちなみにUserDefaultsは内容をすべてキャッシュするのでUserDefaultsに移してもメモリの消費量は変わりません。ずっとインメモリです。